# jsTree not rendering list properly?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jstree

I'm trying to use jsTree and going through the first example on their site just results in a normal list, not tree stylized.  I have this div

```
  <div id="jstree">
    <!-- in this example the tree is populated from inline HTML -->
    <ul>
      <li>Root node 1
        <ul>
          <li id="child_node_1">Child node 1</li>
          <li>Child node 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Root node 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

and this javascript at the bottom.

`<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#jstree").jstree();
        });
    </script>`

The list displays normally, just regular HTML, not as a tree like it should.  There are no errors in the console.

The jsTree js file is included after jquery1.9.1 in the Site.Master file, which is linked to this page through the MasterPageFile.

I'm using ASP.NET for the site, I didn't think it would matter but maybe it does?  I thought it would be straightforward.

I'm assuming I'm missing something simple, any ideas?

Comment: If you look at the ID of your div on the client, does it match what it is on the server?

Comment: @mason I'm not sure what you mean by that. In my aspx page the div id is jstree.  When I run the page and examine the element the div id is still jstree.  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: By default, the ID on the client and the server are different (when master pages or other compositing techniques are used). It's an important distinction. See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968798/using-javascript-from-an-asp-net-textbox/27970691#27970691). But if you're positive that the ID on the client side when you inspect the resulting HTML is `jstree` then you're having a different issue.

Answer (score 3):

Just had the same problem, it turns out styles were missing. I am aware of that it has been more than two years since OP asked the question, but anyone who faces the same problem can give it a shot after adding those and fixing the relative paths:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/themes/default/style.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/themes/default-dark/style.min.css">
```

**Edit:**
Demo files in jstree.zip do not work because of the broken jQuery link. Replace:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

with:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

(or with another up-to-date link when you're working on this) and voila!

Comment: It may have been 2 years since OP asked the question, but almost 3 years after that, your answer helped me out! Thanks!

Comment: @Sterno glad to hear that!